# How to Find the object of The ListItem in ListBox in Windows Phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a ListBox, here i am binding IList Like (Cities).

I want an event like OnItemDataBound in .NET in Windows Phone7.

Like when every city was binded (if 10 cities are this event will fire 10 times) this event will fire so that i have to do some more calculations on this event. In this event i have to find the object binded to the ListItem so that i can make some calculations. Is there any event in WP7 similar OnItemDataBound in .NET.

```
<ListBox Loaded="lstFlights_Loaded" Height="635" x:Name="lstFlights"   
                         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border CornerRadius="10" Margin="10">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/rowbg.png"></ImageBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
//Some data here
     </Border>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

i am binding the data like below:

```
lstFlights.ItemsSource = objCities;
```

on Binding every city i want an event to populate some list items(like: i want to change the textblock text,etc) according to the City that binded to ListItem. To do this I need an event like OnItemDataBound in WP7. And I have list picker like below:

On SelectionChanged event also i want to change the list items.

**And one more thing IList(objCities) is coming from the Service so I can't change that Object
so if i want to change any TextBlock in List Box i have do FindName and i have to assign calculated value for every city binded.**

Comment: Why can't you do the calculations before binding it to the list?

Comment: the response i am getting from the service is very complex so i want do the calculations after binding it. and also i have a listpicker, on selection change also i have to change the calculations of ListBox, That's why i want OnItemDataBound event. Please tell if there is any event like that.

Comment: Can you show what you have right now? I'm not aware of an OnItemDataBound event, but for selection changes you could use the selectionchanged event to handle the situations where you have to do calculations on user selections.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ChristiaanV. I have edited my question please see it once and tel me how can i proceed here.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `CollectionChanged` event in `ObservableCollection` collection for new elements added/removed.

`ListBox` provides some methods for accessing `ListBoxItem`. You can see them in `list.ItemContainerGenerator` class.

You can use it together to achieve needed results.

There is short example that shows how to make a red foreground to newly added items in some conditions (even or not):

```
ObservableCollection<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        items.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (e.NewItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        ListBoxItem listitem = (ListBoxItem)list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
                        if (DateTime.Parse(listitem.Content.ToString()).Second % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            listitem.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        };
        list.ItemsSource = items;            
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }

    private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            int index = rnd.Next(0, items.Count);
            items.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ku6opr. But I don't have any ObservableCollection in My app. I have a IList and I am binding listbox using ItemsSource. Here i want a event like OnItemDataBound .

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `ItemsChanged` event of your `ListBox`'s `ItemContainerGenerator` instead?

```
this.myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventHandler(ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged);

void ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add) 
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Xin. But here how can i find my ListItems, for example I have a TextBlock in Listbox for that text box i have to bind price, So for this i will made some calculation and i will get price but how can i find the TextBlock in this event. In .net we will do like below in OnItemDataBound event:                                                    RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)e.Item;
        City city= (City)item.DataItem;
Literal litPrice = (Literal)item.FindControl("litPrice");

Comment: in ItemsChanged event: `DependencyObject listitem = list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(e.Position.Index + e.Position.Offset);` `DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listitem, 0);` and so on...

Comment: thanks for the reply Ku6opr. But I am not able find listitem using DependencyObject listitem = list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(e.Position.Index + e.Position.Offset); listitem i am getting as null.

Comment: Try this,  var item = (ListBoxItem)myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(myListBox.Items.Count - 1);

Comment: Xin:I have tried above code also but still listitem i am getting as null.